# Why is `exec()` not working in a script but working interactively?

Tags: python, exec

I'm reading in a credentials file to a string and then running `exec()` on that string to make the various credentials available as variables. The credentials file contains text like the following:

```
customer_number = "9999999999"
PIN             = "9999999999"
passcode        = "9999999999"
account_code    = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

This works in interactive Python (with the variables becoming available) but fails in a script. Why is this and how can I get it to work?

```
with open(filepath_credentials, "r") as file_credentials:
    credentials = file_credentials.read()
    exec(credentials)
print(customer_number)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `globals()` (and possibly also `locals()`) collection to `exec()`:

```
exec(credentials, globals())
```

This allows `exec()` to modify your script's global variables. The Python interactive interpreter works slightly differently here.

Comment: But should they really be using `exec()` at all to read in data like this?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Sure, using exec() is not the best way to read a config file under all circumstances, but there are plenty of situations where this is perfectly adequate and not a security risk or anything.